# Mutate new character col based on another character col in oracle table using R dbplyr

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a `oracle` table with a `col COMPLAINT_REASON`

```
complaints_tbl %>% head() %>% select(COMPLAINT_REASON)

# Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# Database: Oracle 12.01.0020[user@user_db/]
  COMPLAINT_REASON         
  <chr>                    
1 Payment Related          
2 Bill Related          
3 Order Management          
4 Repair/Connection related
5 Broadband
6 Product fault
```

I am trying to create a new col called `primary_reason` but with different values i.e. if the `COMPLAINT_REASON` = `Payment Related` then the `primary_reason` should have `Payments`. If `none` are matched then have the value as is in the `primary_reason` column.

In normal circumstance, I would do something like this using `data.table`:

```r
complaints_tbl <- complaints_tbl[,primary_reason := forcats::fct_recode(COMPLAINT_REASON,
    "Payments"    = "Payment Related",
    "Billing"    = "Bill Related",
    "Orders"    = "Order Management",
    "Billing"    = "Billing/Payment Enquiry")]
```

As you can see the ones that are not available will come under `primary reason` as is. (`Product fault, Broadband, Repair/Connection related)` and `Payment Related` becomes `Payments` etc. in the `primary_reason`.

I have tried:

```r
complaints_tbl %>% mutate(primary_reason = forcats::fct_recode(COMPLAINT_REASON
    "Payments"    = "Payment Related",
    "Billing"    = "Bill Related",
    "Orders"    = "Order Management",
    "Billing"    = "Billing/Payment Enquiry"))
```

But getting the error:

```r
Error in check_factor(.f) : object 'COMPLAINT_REASON' not found
```

Lastly, it will be ideal to push the new col back to my existing table in `oracle` for future use.

Any pointers?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work in SQL server not oracle, but I think the challenge here is ensuring `dbplyr` can translate your commands to the database language regardless of your choice of language.

In general `dbplyr` struggles to translate commands outside the `dplyr` or `tidyverse` collection. Hence why `forcats::fct_recode` is not working for you.

An example solution using `ifelse`, which gets translated correctly in my environment:

```
complaints_tbl %>%
  # create column for ease of changes
  mutate(primary_reason = NA) %>%
  # one mutate per match/rename
  mutate(primary_reason = ifelse(COMPLAINT_REASON = "Payment Related",
                                 yes = "Payments", no = primary_reason)) %>%
  mutate(primary_reason = ifelse(COMPLALINT_REASON = "Billing Related",
                                 yes = "Billing", no = primary_reason)) %>%
  # if none are matched
  mutate(primary_reason = ifelse(is.na(primary_reason),
                                 yes = COMPLAINT_REASON, no = primary_reason))
```

Instead of multiple mutates with `ifelse`, you could instead use `case_when`.